# Remove span from Editable when that part of text is changed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to apply styles to an input field so that when a user types the word "congratulations" it becomes bold. The problem I'm having is that when the user starts deleting text, the letters left are still bold until they are all removed.

i.e. if someone typed "hi there, **congratulations**" and then started removing letters, they'd see "hi there, **congratu**" instead of "hi there, congratu".

This is the code I'm using

```java
private class StyleListener implements TextWatcher {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    s = new SpannableStringBuilder(congratStyle(s));
  }
}

public static Spannable congratStyle(Spannable message) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("congratulations");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);

  while (matcher.find()) {
    message.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  }

  return message;
}
```

I tried doing `message = new SpannableStringBuilder(message.toString());` before `while (matcher.find()) {` to clear the text of any spans and then re-apply the bold, but then the bold no longer gets applied at all, i.e. it results in "hi there, congratulations".

Ideally, I'd like to remove the span when the text within the span is changed, but clearing all spans and then re-applying the bold span where applicable is also an acceptable option.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
message.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

to

```
message.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_COMPOSING);
```

Comment: This almost works, but occasionally when deleting a space that occurs after the spannable it chooses to remove the bold despite not being affected, e.g. going from "hi there, **congratulations** my friend" to "hi there, **congratulations** my", upon removing the space between my and friend the bold disappears, and gets re-added after removing a character from my or adding the space back in

Comment: It turns out it's sufficient to move the typing indicator over a space, not even deleting the space, to cause the bold to disappear... very odd